# Oracle Procedure: concurrency and CLOB variable

Tags: oracle, stored-procedures, concurrency

I have following snippet in a stored procedure. The procedure is called from an insert trigger.

```
v_ProdName VARCHAR2(250);
v_ID VARCHAR2(50);
v_Clob CLOB;
-- ....
SELECT      
   MY_TABLE.ID, 
   MY_TABLE.PRODNAME, 
   MY_TABLE.MY_CLOB   
  INTO
   v_ID,
   v_ProdName,
   v_Clob
  FROM   
-- ...
```

Afterwards those 3 variables are used in a call to a function and that function (3rd party) inserts a new record.

This works. However there is an issue with the CLOB insert above. If multiple rows are inserted quickly after each other (example: import from csv with sql developer "insert" method" or WebMethod; I assume inserts happen in same transaction) the CLOB has for all rows the value of the first inserted rows. All others (eg id, ProdName) have the correct value.

Therefore it seems the Clob is somehow cached. Is that true? How can I fix that behavior?

EDIT:

Example:

```
DECLARE

-- ... variables
    v_id varchar2(15);

BEGIN

-- assign values to vars, one of them is an ID on which CLOB is selected
    -- in the procedure
    v_id := '754-56-4';

my_procedure(v_id, args);

    -- if this commit in un-commented, it works as expected.
    -- eg. the 2 inserted rows have different values for the clob field
-- COMMIT;


-- assign other values to vars especially different id
    -- -> result should have a different value in CLOB field        
    v_id := '5356-97-6';

my_procedure(v_id, args);

END;
```

Note that all other fields selected based in v_id have the correct value regardless if the COMMIT is made or not! So it is an issue with CLOB not the procedure!!!

Comment: Why do you need to perform a SELECT in an INSERT trigger? Can't you reference the inserted data directly?

Comment: Nope. The trigger only get an "id" on which additional information is looked up (SELECT). The table the trigger runs on is filled by WebMethod (eg. messaging) and the procedure called in the trigger then moves the data + additional data from lookup to the final destination. not all received rows are transferred. anyway this has nothing to do with the issue.

Comment: Can you test this directly with an INSERT statement (instead of via .csv Import / WebMethod)?

Comment: It seems to be consistent behavior of Oracle, at least my instance. I can run the procedure multiple times in an anonymous block and get the same behavior. If I add a commit between calls, it works as I would expect.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

This issue was caused by a bug in the 3rd party function.